# What were the power sources of the rings from Captain Planet?

Tags: science, physics, captain-planet

Captain Planet's 'Planeteers' each have a powerful ring.

What is the source of their power and does the use of this power itself cause pollution (e.g. is their use a case of "*the greater good*")?

Comment: Are you looking for real world physics to explain fictional ones? If so, this question is likely off-topic. If not, please clarify your question.

Comment: If you think breaking a law of physics is an ethical matter, maybe avoid most superhero fiction.  They just don't get along with physics.

Comment: @Skooba I'm looking for any explanation to their power source, and speculated at one possible.

Comment: They use Gaia's power.

Comment: I've done a big edit to reflect your comment about their power source and whether their use is itself polluting.

Comment: @Valorum Thanks!

Comment: Should this still be on hold?

Comment: Oil, burning barrels of oil